# setting thread priorities in C

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, posix

How do I know if a thread in C is "running", "runnable", "blocked" or "terminated". I do know such functions exist in Java but cant find them in C....

Also, I need multiple threads with multiple priorities, I did use **pthread_attr_setschedparam**, with a **SCHED_RR** policy and **EXPLICIT inheritance** but it dose'nt seem to work?

Any suggestions where I am going wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please visit the link describing [**How to Ask a Question**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). Providing the necessary details, including your code, and associated errors, if any, will allow everyone here to help you with your question.

Comment: @David I don't see what's missing with this question. The question is clear and all requirements for an answer are provided. What is missing for you? OP asked about how to enquire about certain information, why do you need code for that?

Comment: Hey, Can I know how to do it ?

Comment: Did you initialize your `pthread_attr_t` variables using `pthread_attr_init` ?

Comment: yes, i initialized it using pthread_attr_init()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will tell you the sequence which has to be followed to assign scheduling policy to your threads.

1) First you create you `pthread_attr_t attr` variable.

2) Initialize it - `pthread_attr_init(&attr)`.

3) Set explicit inheritance: `pthread_attr_setinheritsched(&attr,PTHREAD_EXPLICIT_SCHED);`

4) Then set your scheduling policy using `pthread_attr_setschedpolicy(&attr,SCHED_RR);`

5) Finally create your thread `pthread_create(&THREAD_NAME, &attr, FN_NAME, ARGS);`

You can use this `attr` variable to create as many threads as you want with `SCHED_RR` policy.

Now how do you check, whether the required policy is set or not ? You have to use `pthread_attr_getschedpolicy` function. Refer MAN page to know how to use it http://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_attr_getschedpolicy

Use should not use `pthread_attr_setschedparam` for setting `SCHED_RR` policy to the threads. This function is used to assign priorities to your threads. Refer http://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_attr_setschedparam for more details.